# How to concat query results?

Tags: google-sheets

I've got data like this:

```
A          | B
-----------------------
Date       | Data
30/06/2015 | 1.2
01/07/2015 | 2
01/07/2015 | 3
02/07/2015 | 2
02/07/2015 | 3
```

And I write a simple query like this:

```
=query(A:B; "select YEAR(A) || ' ' || month(A), SUM(B)
    group by YEAR(A), month(A)")
```

But I've got a "Value Error", so I write this

```
=query(A:B; "select YEAR(A), MONTH(A), SUM(B)
    group by YEAR(A), month(A)")
```

And it work well, but, how can I concat two values in one cell ?

I though of this:

```
=QUERY(Journal!A:B;"select A, SUM(B)
    group by A
    format A 'yyyy-MM'")
```

But the format operation is done AFTER the group by so it's like the group by never was.

Any idea ?

[Solution]

```
=query({Arrayformula(text(Foo!A:A; "yyyy-MM")) \Foo!B:B}; "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1"; -1)
```

Because my local is "french" I've to use the '\' in the Arrrayformula and ; instead of ','...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ampersand (&) to concatenate in arrayformula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A:A), year(A:A)&" "&month(A2:A),))
```

or if you don't want the space between year and month:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A:A), year(A:A)&month(A2:A),))
```

EDIT:

If you want to query and sum, try:

```
=query({Arrayformula(text(Journal!A:A, "yyyy-MM")),Journal!B:B}, "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1", 0)
```

or in locale that use semi-colons as argument separators:

```
=query({Arrayformula(text(Journal!A:A; "yyyy-MM"))\Journal!B:B}; "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"; 0)
```

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YwgCd43vkUATH_cvaFBKYfgWn9s4WzV1GSfBqlIso7E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

But what I did not says (my fault) was that I do other things in my query, and I would like it to be in the query.

I suppose I can't call ArrayFormula in my query, can I ?

Comment: The text() function doest not accept area, only a cell (or value)

Comment: Ok, you sampl does not work for me...
Maybe the fact is that I'm french... so I made a new [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1le130_1DAhnnj_xPmKFrbMrjdkUPpL_YTL6uiqanwcg/edit?usp=sharing) but columns names are not Col1 or Col2... any idea how can I get those ? `select *` return nothing...

Comment: it's a locale issue. In your locale the literal array {} should be written like this: ={Arrayformula(text(Foo!A:A; "yyyy-MM")) \ Foo!B:B}. Check the example sheet again. I changed it so it matches your locale.